# The FizzBuzz challenge in Java 8 written in a short, readable and interesting way

Tags: java, programming-challenge, fizzbuzz, java-8

I decided to take on the FizzBuzz challenge with as twist that I would use Java 8 concepts to make it a bit modular, yet still let it be a short, readable and understandable program.

This in contrary to some gem I found on the net: [FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition](https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition)

The problem description:

> Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz"

Here's my code:

```
public class FizzBuzz {
    private static Stream<String> fizzBuzz(final int min, final int max) {
        if (min < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("min is negative: min = " + min);
        }
        if (min > max) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("min > max: min = " + min + " / max = " + max);
        }
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max)
                .mapToObj(FizzBuzz::fizzBuzzify);
    }

    private static String fizzBuzzify(final int value) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean toDefault = true;
        if (value % 3 == 0) {
            stringBuilder.append("Fizz");
            toDefault = false;
        }
        if (value % 5 == 0) {
            stringBuilder.append("Buzz");
            toDefault = false;
        }
        return (toDefault) ? String.valueOf(value) : stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fizzBuzz(1, 100).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I'm still looking for a nicer way to write `fizzBuzzify`, my intention however is to **not** hardcode the `if (value % 15 == 0)` similarly `if (value % 3 == 0 && value % 5 == 0)`, because it creates a sort of illogical operation precedence, being that you absolutely need to write the `if (value % 15 == 0)` case up front, followed by the 3-case and the 5-case (or vica versa).

Comment: In my view, any solution to FizzBuzz that doesn't use a simple for loop and System.out.println fails the test.

Comment: you already have that operation precedence. if the order is not as you have it you'd never write FizzBuzz

Comment: @RuneFS I am aware of that, but first 3 and then 5 feels logical to my, whereas a sequence of <15, 3, 5> or <15, 5, 3> do not feel logical to me.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I think that hardcoding values/operations is a sin. And that's exactly what you are doing when you hardcode `System.out.println`, and the `IntStream.rangeClosed` is in a sense nothing more and nothing less than a glorified for-loop, but it does open up the possibility to easily return a `Stream<String>`, which supports my first point as now you can do whatever you want with the results.

Comment: logic is not something you can feel. It either is or is not. The "feeling" part was my point exactly

Comment: @RemcoGerlich there's nothing in the FizzBuzz challenge that requires the solution to be imperative as far as I can see. Why do you make that claim?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I just want to emphasize again that `Stream.forEach` is a for-loop.  (skiwi wrote it above, but it was not that clear.)  I quite like functional programming: the code can be broken down in finer sub-units than simple OO.  And those sub-units can be reused.  Take a look at my answer for example where I managed to extract some pattern that could be useful elsewhere than FizzBuzz.

Comment: @Rune FS: It's not in the challenge, but it's just not good programming to make a program much more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: @REmcoGerlich using a for loop is more complex that writing this purely functional.

Comment: @RuneFS Because you say so? And this is Java, nothing is ever gonna be purely functional in it, so what is the point of your comment?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich A for loop is an imperative way of iterating, a projection is a declarative way of doing that. The cyclomatic complexity of the for loop is higher than that of the projection (there's no branching/jumping in a projection). You can do projections in Java

Comment: @RuneFS: I know. But still, FizzBuzz is meant as a *sanity check*, the simplest possible thing you can ask somebody to see if they can program at least a little bit. The answer should reflect that. Arguing whether it's better to print "FizzBuzz" or "Fizz" and then "Buzz", or whether things are hardcoded, or caring whether you can do whatever you want with the result, or breaking code down into fine sub-units, extracting patterns, or thinking about cyclomatic complexity is missing the point. Just write a few lines, that's the question. Three methods and several classes used is not simple.

Comment: I'm not arguing against the point of FizzBuzz being a sanity check and only commented on complexity because you claimed that a for loop was required because anything else would make the program more complex than it needed to be. As you said your self I think a discussion about complexity is beside the point for a simple program as this and simply believe that there are several sane implementations with out a for loop

Comment: I can't add my solution cause I don't have enough karma here but this is my java 8 gist https://gist.github.com/gicappa/a3995fb39d6ccdd09daf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A guideline that I use for deciding on a `StringBuilder` or not is that it depends on whether I know beforehand how many times it will be used or not. I believe I've come across this recommendation on some MSDN page once but I'm not entirely sure.

In your case, you know that there are only two possible uses of your `StringBuilder`, and that there are no values added inside a loop, so I would use normal string concatenation:

Now you can also change your code a little to what I consider more easily interpretable:

```
private static String fizzBuzzify(final int value) {
   String result = "";

   if (value % 3 == 0) {
       result += "Fizz";
   }
   if (value % 5 == 0) {
       result += "Buzz";
   }
   return result.length() > 0 ? result : Integer.toString(value);
}
```

Comment: Very good catch on the `result.length > 0`, I like it! No need for the (stupid) variable anymore.

Comment: Slightly nicer than `result.length > 0` is `!result.isEmpty()`

Comment: @janos: I can't say I'm a particular fan of that. While technically a string *is* a container of chars, it still feels as if it's mainly a basic object and not a datastructure. `.isEmpty()` is something I associate with collections.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel in my head the logic goes as "if the string is empty, do this, or else that", and not "if the string has length bigger than 0", so writing it that way feels natural. Incidentally, collections have an `isEmpty` method too, but that doesn't bother me at all

Comment: @JeroenVannevel At least in English, a zero-length string is called an empty string, and `isEmpty` makes perfect sense.

Comment: While this is better than the `StringBuilder`, just returning one of three constant interned literals is better yet.  Even if it feels righteous to build `"FizzBuzz"` as the combination of meeting both Fizz and Buzz rules, all it accomplishes is creating a lot of garbage strings.

Comment: @janos I agree with using `.isEmpty()` however I don't see any reason for the negation. I'd Flip the second and third operand instead

Comment: @RuneFS I also prefer to flip it. My second comment implies it, but you're right I should have written like that up front

Comment: No need to use ```+=``` for ```"Fizz"```  just assign the value.  Also, you could initialize ```result``` to null and change the "Buzz" if body to ```result = (result == null) ? "Buzz" : "FizzBuzz";```  Then you aren't generating so much garbage.

Answer (score 15):

I think if you're going to do this, it's better to separate out the conditions. I don't know Java 8 well enough to use it, but in older Java, I'd consider something like this (note that this isn't intended to be compilable Java, just Java-like pseudocode):

```
interface Substitute {
    Boolean condition(int);
    String transform(int);
}

class Fizzer : implements Substitute {
    Boolean condition(int x) { return x % 3 == 0; }
    String transform(int) { return "fizz"; }
};

class Buzzer : implements Substitute {
    Boolean condition(int x) { return x % 5 == 0; }
    String transform(int) { return "buzz"; }
};

class Mapper {
    List<Substitute> subs;

    void add_sub(Substitute sub) {
        subs.Add(sub);
    }    

    String execute(int input) { 
        String result;
        Boolean use_default = true;

        foreach (sub : subs) {
            if (sub.condition(input)) {
                result += sub.transform(input);
                use_default = false;
            }
        }
        if (use_default) return String.valueOf(input);
        return result;
    }
}

class FizzBuzz {
    static void main() { 
        Mapper map;
        map.add_sub(new Fizzer);
        map.add_sub(new Buzzer);

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
           System.out.println(map.execute(i));
    }
}
```

This separates out the basic concept of "if some condition is met, substitute a string for the number" from the individual conditions and results produced. Like yours, however, it still doesn't *entirely* avoid depending on ordering to some degree (and I don't think such dependency can be avoided). If you don't maintain ordering of the substitutions, you could end up replacing a multiple of 15 with "buzzfizz" instead of the required "fizzbuzz".

To avoid that, you have a couple of choices. One is to maintain an ordered list of the mapping objects, and run all of them in order for every input. If two or more fire, you concatenate the results together, and it's up to the client code to order appropriately.

Alternatively, you can stop at the first one that "fires" (i.e., the first one for which the "condition" returns true). This requires that the client code include a "FizzBuzzer" that will "fire" for multiples of 15.

Personally, I'd prefer to use that, and extend it a bit further. Instead of the ugly conditional code in the loop that decides whether a transformation has already happened, or to use the default transformation (i.e., just printing out the number), I'd prefer to just add a default transformation to the end of the list of transformations:

```
class DefaultMap : implements Substitute {
    Boolean condition(int) { return true; }
    String transform(int val) { return String.valueOf(val); }
};

// ... in main:
Mapper map;

map.add_sub(new FizzBuzzer);
map.add_sub(new Fizzer);
map.add_sub(new Buzzer);
map.add_sub(new DefaultMap);

for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
    System.out.println(map.execute(i));
```

As far as the code itself goes, the way I've written it is fairly verbose. Although I don't know Java 8 well enough to actually write the code to do it, I feel fairly confident that it would allow the substitutions to be written as lambda expressions, which should substantially reduce verbosity without loss of generality (and given my ignorance of Java 8, I'd almost be surprised if it didn't allow other improvements as well).

Comment: I like this one, I was actually experimenting with this whole creating the current solution. I'll be sure to make a little library class to hold the different options and I'll create a followup using this!

Comment: It would be better if the classes turned into humble methods...java 8, you know. Less enterprise-y.

Comment: I don't think Java has `foreach`.

Comment: @SimonKuang: "note that this isn't intended to be compilable Java, just Java-like pseudocode". In a nearly C++-like avoidance of introducing new keywords, Java just extended the `for` syntax to provide foreach-like semantics.

Comment: OMG..why make simple things this complex?

Answer (score 7):

For a trivially simple use case like this, StringBuilder is overkill. Use simple concatenation instead:

```
String result = "";
if (value % 3 == 0) {
    result = "Fizz";
}
if (value % 5 == 0) {
    result += "Buzz";
}
```

The brackets around `toDefault` here are unnecessary:

```
return (toDefault) ? String.valueOf(value) : stringBuilder.toString();
```

How about a convenience generator with only a `max` argument, using `min=1` by default:

```
static Stream<String> fizzBuzz(final int max) {
    return fizzBuzz(1, max);
}
```

How about adding some unit tests:

```
public class FizzBuzzTest {
    private String resultToString(int from, int to) {
        return FizzBuzz.fizzBuzz(from, to).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    @Test
    public void testShortRanges() {
        assertEquals("1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz", resultToString(1, 6));
        assertEquals("7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz", resultToString(7, 15));
    }

    @Test
    public void testConsistentConcat() {
        String a = resultToString(1, 20);
        String b = resultToString(21, 100);
        assertEquals(a + " " + b, resultToString(1, 100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to quote [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33724/41243) as you've made the same mistake in interpreting the requirements. Although, I'm not sure how many interviewers would catch the difference. You should be prepared to explain *why* it's better to use `value % 3 == 0 && value % 5 ==0` over the solution you've implemented or over hard coding the value of 15.

> > Write a program that prints the integers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz"
>
> However you have implemented this:
>
> > Write a program that prints the integers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print *the concatenation of both.*
>
> Why does it matter? If you consider the problem as the business logic given provided by a customer then approx. 5sec after the deployment of your solution the customer will come back and say: "Ah yes, I forgot, if it's divisible by 3 and 5 you have to print FixBugz because some of our legacy applications which we can't change have a typo in their parsing code." Now instead of just changing array(3 => 'Fizz', 5 => 'Buzz', 15 => 'FizzBuzz') into array(3 => 'Fizz', 5 => 'Buzz', 15 => 'FixBugz') you have to change a whole bunch of implementation code and unit tests.

I'm not very good with Java, but I like [this answer's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56913/41243) implementation, so I'm going to make a slight improvement to it. Instead of hard coding all those magic numbers, FizzBuzzify should take some parameters. I explain this fully in [this answer to a different FizzBuzz question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/56893/41243).

```
private static String fizzBuzzify(final int value, final int fizzDivisor, final int buzzDivisor) {
  if (value % fizzDivisor == 0) {
    return (value % buzzDivisor == 0) ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz";  
  }
  return (value % buzzDivisor == 0) ? "Buzz" : Integer.toString(value);
}
```

I would recommend making `fizzDivisor` and `buzzDivisor` optional parameters with default values though. I just don't know how that's done in Java.

Comment: The customer is equally likely to tell you that Buzz should change to Bugz, and expect the FizzBuzz print to change accordingly. You're way overthinking this.

Comment: I think everyone over thinks FizzBuzz @RemcoGerlich. That why I say it's important to be able to explain your thought process; whatever it may be.

Answer (score 5):

Except for the StringBuilder, I agree with your solution.

I wrote a completely different solution which I think it is more "functional".  It might not be the most efficient solution, but this code is *reusable* for different problems.

```
/**
 * @return a function that simply returns its input value, except that it 
 *         returns {@code overWriteValue} each time the function as been
 *         called a multiple of {@code periodicity} times.
 */
public static <T> Function<T, T> overWriter(int periodicity, T overWriteValue) {
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    return value -> (counter.getAndIncrement() % periodicity) == 0  
                        ? overWriteValue 
                        : value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stream<String> ints = IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(Integer::toString);
    Function<String, String> fizzBuzzOverWriter = 
            overWriter(3, "Fizz")
            .andThen(overWriter(5, "Buzz")
            .andThen(overWriter(15, "FizzBuzz")));
    Stream<String> fizzBuzz = ints.map(fizzBuzzOverwriter);
    fizzBuzz.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Note that I am not at all using the value of the integers when choosing the overwrite value.  You have to make sure the start value of the Stream and the initial counter value are in some agreement.  (I could also have added the initial counter value as an argument to `overWrite()`.)

I could also have made my `overWrite` function: `Integer` -> `String`.  But the code is then less reusable, if at all.  Also, composing the three different overlapping conditions would not be as simple.

Comment: At least to me, this seems a bit too clever and *far* too easy to use in ways that *look* like they should work, but will actually fail completely. An interesting solution nonetheless.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Could you please explain?  I'm used to functional programming (Scala), so this is not "clever" at all to me.  And what about "*look* like they should work"?  This code gave me the right answer right away.  I did not have to do any debugging.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin And by the way, my code is nearly identical to yours, but terser since I'm using Java 8.  `Function` is your `Substitute` and function composition (`andThen`) is nearly equivalent to your `Mapper`.

Comment: I'm talking about the fact that `overWriter` uses its own internal counter, so if (for example) you tried to get a sequence starting from another number (e.g., 25) instead of 1, the output would be entirely wrong.

Comment: Yeah, having four independently incrementing counters is a code smell here.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think it's better to test for divisibility by the second term in the first `if` (and you did not forbid the ternary) so,

```
private static String fizzBuzzify(final int value) {
  if (value % 3 == 0) {
    return (value % 5 == 0) ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz";  
  }
  return (value % 5 == 0) ? "Buzz" : Integer.toString(value);
}
```

This way there are no extra temporaries in the method.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with an `enum` to define the substitiutions, something like:

```
private static enum Transformer implements IntFunction<Optional<String>> {
    FIZZ {
        @Override
        public Optional<String> apply(int value) {
            return value % 3 == 0 ? Optional.of("Fizz") : Optional.empty();
        }
    },
    BUZZ {
        @Override
        public Optional<String> apply(int value) {
            return value % 5 == 0 ? Optional.of("Buzz") : Optional.empty();
        }
    };
}
```

So now you can easily add new "transformations" to the list.

In order to transform an `int` to the correct `String` in Scala we would simple use `flatMap` as `Option` is also a collection. No such luck in Java. I came up with this thing, it's a little ugly but I think it's clear:

```
private static String transform(final int i) {
    final StringBuilder sb = Stream.of(Transformer.values()).
            map(t -> t.apply(i)).
            collect(StringBuilder::new, (builder, v) -> v.ifPresent(builder::append), StringBuilder::append);
    if (sb.length() == 0) {
        sb.append(i);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Essentially we take each `transformer` and we `apply` it that gives us a `Stream<Optional<String>>`. I then you the `collect` method to append all present instances to a `StringBuilder`. If the `StringBuilder is empty simply append the current integer too.

An alternative, not sure if it's better, is:

```
private static String transform(final int i) {
    return Stream.of(Transformer.values()).
            map(t -> t.apply(i)).
            filter(Optional::isPresent).
            map(Optional::get).
            collect(collectingAndThen(joining(), s -> s.isEmpty() ? Integer.toString(i) : s));
}
```

Here we do the `map` to get the `Stream<Optional<String>>`, we then `filter` out `absent` and `map` to a `Stream<String>`. We then use the (often overlooked) `collectingAndThen` `Collector` to first `join` the resulting `Stream<String>` and then to return `i` if the joined `String` is empty.

The main work now becomes as simple as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).mapToObj(App::transform).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can further enhance the code in [Jeroen Vannevel's answer](/a/56830/75307) (which doesn't use `StringBuilder` when it isn't helping, and removes an unneeded boolean variable) with the following further improvements:

- eliminate any string concatenation and generation of garbage strings, and
- eliminate need for additional boolean or method calls to `length()` or `isEmpty()` as some other answers suggest.

The result is:

```
private static String fizzBuzzify(final int value) {
   String result = null;

   if (value % 3 == 0) {
       result = "Fizz";
   }
   if (value % 5 == 0) {
       result = (result == null) ? "Buzz" : "FizzBuzz";
   }
   return (result != null) ? result : Integer.toString(value);
}
```

My Java 8-ified answer uses `mapToObj()` to transform the output without any redundant checks or added booleans by recognizing 15 as the common factor of 3 and 5 so the conditions can be written in clear discreet steps.  I don't see the need to complicate this with extra methods, so there is simply one lambda expression to map the values, and a method reference to `System.out.println` for the output I/O to the `forEach()` method:

```
    public static void fizzBuzz() {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
                .mapToObj(n -> (n%15 == 0) ? "FizzBuzz"
                              : (n%3 == 0) ? "Fizz"
                              : (n%5 == 0) ? "Buzz"
                              : Integer.toString(n))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: Note that the existence of old (>5 years) "answers" that don't provide a proper review does not mean that you should do the same, in 2022.

Comment: @TobySpeight expanded my description a bit.  I had summarized the advantages a bit too much I guess.  Is it okay now?

Comment: It now appears to be a review of one of the other _answers_.  I don't see where you make any observations about _the code in the question_.

Comment: @TobySpeight Unnecessary String building in some form was part of the original, as was an extra boolean.  My answer differs from others in how it deals with that.  No concatenation at all, no need for extra method calls when eliminating the boolean.

Comment: Right, but as you say, Jeroen's answer already addresses the unnecessary string-building and the boolean, so the only original part of this answer is the recommendation not to use `length()` or `empty()` (which don't appear to be used at all in the question code)?  It certainly seems like you're reviewing Jeroen's code rather than skiwi's code.

Comment: @TobySpeight No, Jeroen's answer still has string concatenation.  I suggested alterations that removed the string generation and better addressed the removal of the boolean.  Is there some requirement to say more?

Comment: @TobySpeight I've reworded the answer to hopefully make my suggested changes clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It says "print", so I'll use sysout. Both solutions are IMHO also relatively short and readable.

I assume that "FizzBuzz" is meant as a concatenation of "Fizz" and "Buzz". That might not be true, but it's nicer here, I think.

The first one uses uses the Consumer-Interface which was added to Java in Version 8.

```
class FizzBuzzConsumer implements IntConsumer {

    @Override
    public void accept(int value) {
        if (value % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.print("Fuzz");
        }
        if (value % 5 == 0) {
            System.out.print("Buzz");
        }
        if (value % 3 != 0 && value % 5 != 0) {
            System.out.print(value);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The `FizzBuzzConsumer` takes an int-Value and decides what to print. It does not care whether the int-Value is a multiple of both 3 *and* 5, because that condition can be fulfilled by each separately.

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FizzBuzzConsumer fizzBuzzConsumer = new FizzBuzzConsumer();

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .forEach(fizzBuzzConsumer);
    }
}
```

This created a stream of integers, each of which is fed into the `FizzBuzzConsumer`.

Another solution which simply looks at each int in the stream (`peek`) to decide whether to print Fizz and/or Buzz or the value itself:

```
public class FizzBuzz2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .peek(possibleMultipleOfThree -> {
                if (possibleMultipleOfThree % 3 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Fizz");
                }
            })
            .peek(possibleMultipleOfFive -> {
                if (possibleMultipleOfFive % 5 == 0) {
                    System.out.print("Buzz");
                }
            })
            .peek(possibleMultipleOfNeither -> {
                if (possibleMultipleOfNeither % 3 != 0 && possibleMultipleOfNeither % 5 != 0) {
                    System.out.print(value3);
                }
            })
            .forEach(intValue -> System.out.println());
    }
}
```

Again this creates a stream of integers. It looks ("peeks") at each of them to decide whether what to print, followed by a linebreak. It's more or less the same as above, but much more verbose.

Neither seems particularly interesting to me, though. In both cases I felt that repeating the comparison of the current int-value for the opposite condition (`if (value % 3 != 0 && value % 5 != 0)`) would make for the highest readability.

Comment: Thanks, I added some bits about my motivation for writing these exact pieces of code. I'd like to know what is not particularly good about them, if it's not too much trouble.

Comment: If you'd like to have your code reviewed, you should post your own question.

Comment: Thanks again, I addressed all your remarks, hopefully. I'm still going to assume that "FizzBuzz" is meant as a concatenation of "Fizz" and "Buzz", but I might be wrong!