# FizzBuzz in Ruby

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

I have this implementation of the FizzBuzz challenge in Ruby:

```
(1..100).each do |n|
    i_3=(n%3==0)
    i_5=(n%5==0)
    case
        when i_3&&i_5
            puts 'fizzbuzz'
        when i_3
            puts 'fizz'
        when i_5
            puts 'buzz'
        else
            puts n
    end
end
```

It prints the numbers and words just as I would expect it to.

Is there a way to make this better follow Ruby best practices?

Comment: You may be able to learn a thing or two from one of the four Ruby answers to [this question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/88/18487). Disclaimer: No code on that site follows best practice (on purpose).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- You've inlined the whole program. It would be beneficial to separate FizzBuzz into it's own method that accepts `n` as an argument.
- Speaking of `n`, I discourage the use of one and two letter variable names. `number` would be better.
- I like that you precalculated booleans before entering the select statement, but these two need better names. `divisibleBy3` and `divisibleBy5` would be better.
- I also like that you interpreted the requirements correctly and are not concatenating the results in an attempt to prematurely optimize. [See this for more info.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33724/41243)
- Some of your statements could use some breathing space. `(n % 3)` instead of `(n%3)` etc.
- Brackets aren't necessary in Ruby, but they help to clarify.
- [As @rofl pointed out in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16563900#16563900), you're printing "fizz", "buzz", and "fizzbuzz" instead of "Fizz", "Buzz", and "FizzBuzz".

Implementing my suggestions, you get something like this.

```
def fizzbuzz(number)
    divisibleBy3 = (number % 3 == 0)
    divisibleBy5 = (number % 5 == 0)

    case
        when divisibleBy3 && divisibleBy5
            puts "FizzBuzz"
        when divisibleBy3
            puts "Fizz"
        when divisibleBy5
            puts "Buzz"
        else 
            puts number
    end
end

(1..100).each {|n| fizzbuzz n}
```

Comment: The program was originally built to be code golf, and thus the odd variable names. But I've still learnt something today, thanks!

Comment: A PascalCased method name? My Ruby-sense is tingling...

Comment: I'm afraid there's a lot more here. 1) only methods can  have `?` in their name, 2) but even if it worked, `divisibleBy3? && divisibleBy5?` will always be true since neither will ever be false'y, and 3) using `do` and `{}` for the last block is a syntax error...

Comment: My Ruby n00b is showing I guess. I'll look at it again later.

Comment: It would be fun to extend `Integer` to hold the `divisibleBy3?` and `divisbleBy5?` methods.

Comment: @Flambino. I fixed everything except the `&&`. I got that from OP's code and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Never mind. Figured out my mistake. It should be all good now.

Comment: Trouble is that your `divisibleBy*` variables will always be thruth'y; they'll never be `nil` or `false`. So the code _always_ prints "FizzBuzz" regardless of the number you pass it. You have to compare them against zero somewhere

Comment: Ah, yup, there we go, the very instant I posted my last comment :)

Comment: Break it out of the case statements and you can make the code smaller.  https://gist.github.com/wilkinsbrian/e6fc05fbd6ab96e87cd0

Comment: I'd move the `puts` to the `each` block. More modular, less repetition.

Answer (score 11):

[As ckuhn203 pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56929/14370), the variable names aren't great. In this case, I'd consider just calling them `fizz` and `buzz`.

Otherwise it's OK. There are so many different ways to do this. The `case` statement is a good choice for the usage here, but you could also do:

```
(1..100).each do |number|
  fizz = number % 3 == 0
  buzz = number % 5 == 0
  print "Fizz" if fizz
  print "Buzz" if buzz
  print number if !fizz && !buzz
  print "\n"
end
```

You could also use `print number unless fizz || buzz` but using `unless` with compound conditions can quickly become confusing to read, so I'd rather use good ol' `if` when anything more than a single boolean expression is involved.

Or use string concatenation

```
(1..100).each do |number|
  line = ""
  line << "Fizz" if number % 3 == 0
  line << "Buzz" if number % 5 == 0
  puts line.empty? ? number : line
end
```

Or, if you want a more flexible approach, you could do something like

```
denominators = { "Fizz" => 3, "Buzz" => 5 } # or more

(1..100).each do |number|
  matches = denominators.map { |name, divisor| name if number % divisor == 0 }
  puts matches.any? ? matches.join : number
end
```

Note that hashes are unordered in Ruby 1.8 and below, so it won't necessarily work correctly there, possibly printing "BuzzFizz". However, you can just use nested arrays instead to ensure ordering: `[["Fizz", 3], ["Buzz", 5]]`

And of course, any of these could be wrapped as methods, as ckuhn suggested.

**Update:** So apparently (see comments) the FizzBuzz task can be construed as printing "Fizz", "Buzz" or "FizzBuzz" as separate, distinct strings without using concatenation. The [original problem statement](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-cant-programmers-program/) does not, to my eyes, state this. It simply gives the expected output. From there, it's up to you (which is the point of the task, really)

Still, if the *actual* point is to print 3 *distinct* strings, then you can do something like

```
denominators = { "Whatever" => 15, "Fizz" => 3, "Buzz" => 5 }

# since ordering matters, you could just sort the hash (making it an array in process) to
# have the highest denominators first, like so:
# 
#   denominators.sort_by(&:last).reverse

(1..100).each do |number|
  match = denominators.detect { |name, divisor| number % divisor == 0 }
  puts match ? match.first : number
end
```

But again, I'd argue that the original spec does not require any such thing.

---

This is **just for fun**, because Ruby lets you monkey-patch anything. Of course **you should not** monkey-patch stuff like this "in real-life" - it's a super obnoxious "solution" I've just included for fun.

```
class Fixnum
  alias_method :original_to_s, :to_s

  def to_s
    str = ""
    str << "Fizz" if self % 3 == 0
    str << "Buzz" if self % 5 == 0
    str.empty? ? original_to_s : str
  end
end

puts (1..100).to_a # to_s gets called automatically
```

You just can't print integers normally anymore if you do this :-P

Comment: @Vogel612 I was unaware that that was a requirement. Where do you see that?

Comment: Link from ckuhn203s answer: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33717/oop-style-fizzbuzz-program-in-php/33724#33724 . You will find a more detailed explanation there.. i am currently on mobile and it's 1:30 here, so please accept my apologies for just posting a link ..

Comment: @Vogel612 Hmm... I'd argue that the original (Atwood) spec is unclear then. It just says "For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print 'FizzBuzz'" - nothing more. And that can be achieved just fine with string concatenation. The answer you linked says, in effect, "_what if_ the spec was different?" - or at any rate "what if we read something into the spec?". So it's not the same problem. Still, it's easy enough to do, and I'll add a line, but I call shenanigans.

Comment: The only thing that seems to be generally agreed upon is that the fizzbuzz question is vaguely defined. It's entirely possible that it was *intentionally* vaguely defined.

Comment: @ckuhn203 Agreed, I do believe it's intentionally vague, since interpretation is also up to the coder. And in, say, an interview situation, I'd find it perfectly fine to solve the problem as you read it, and _then_ be told "ok, but what if...?". Adaptability (on the coder's or the code's part) to changing requirements is a good thing to examine. But just giving vague requirements and then faulting a valid solution is shenanigans. Too easy to turn it around and fault it for _not_ using concatenation (or whatever) if it isn't. Damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Comment: Maybe that's the real point of the question. No matter how the programmer implements it, it's vague enough to throw that curveball.

Comment: The point of fizzbuzz is to see whether a candidate can write a simple program. There is no point trying to optimize it, or make it more extensible. That's missing the point. If you can get a fizzbuzz program to compile, run, and print the correct output, you WIN fizzbuzz. Now go write a real program.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer to see counting loops written as `1.upto(100) do … end`.

Ruby `case` blocks are expressions. The `puts` can be factored out:

```
1.upto(100) do |n|
  i_3 = (n % 3 == 0)
  i_5 = (n % 5 == 0)
  puts case
    when i_3 && i_5
      'fizzbuzz'
    when i_3
      'fizz'
    when i_5
      'buzz'
    else
      n
  end
end
```

Personally, I'd go further: instead of treating `i_3` and `i_5` as booleans, assign them a noise.

```
1.upto(100) do |n|
  fizz = (n % 3 == 0) ? 'Fizz' : nil
  buzz = (n % 5 == 0) ? 'Buzz' : nil
  puts case
    when fizz || buzz
      "#{fizz}#{buzz}"
    else
      n
  end
end
```

Or, replace `case` with a ternary expression:

```
1.upto(100) do |n|
  fizz = (n % 3 == 0) ? 'Fizz' : nil
  buzz = (n % 5 == 0) ? 'Buzz' : nil
  puts (fizz || buzz) ? "#{fizz}#{buzz}" : n
end
```

To enhance code reusability, I suggest putting the code into a function, and `yield`ing the results instead of printing them directly.

```
def fizzbuzz(max=100)
  1.upto(max) do |n|
    fizz = (n % 3 == 0) ? 'Fizz' : nil
    buzz = (n % 5 == 0) ? 'Buzz' : nil
    yield (fizz || buzz) ? "#{fizz}#{buzz}" : n
  end
end

fizzbuzz { |fb| puts fb }
```

Note the Ruby whitespace conventions: two spaces of indentation (you used four), and some space on each side of binary operators (you used none).

Comment: Same as with Flambino's answer, you answer does not fulfil the actual requirements in the 2 later codesamples :(

Comment: @Vogel612 Not sure what your objection is, or whether you're being serious.

Comment: A little late, but here goes. The point is, that the "FizzBuzz" part should be a separate if-condition. In [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33717/oop-style-fizzbuzz-program-in-php/33724#33724) ChrisWue elaborates, that, as soon as you change the output for the FizzBuzz condition, you'd need to refactor the whole program. The actual requirement is: For numbers divisible by both 3 AND 5, print "FizzBuzz". What you do is: For numbers divisible by 3 AND 5, print "Fizz" and then "Buzz". and that is a horse of different color.

Comment: @Vogel612 Your concern is misplaced, I think. The output is identical and correct. Should the requirements change, it would be trivial to modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Let's agree to disagree. I can accept that it may be nitpicking in the context of a FizzBuzz itself, but all else equal it's a violation of the acceptance criteria IMO :(

Comment: @Vogel612: If you wanna nitpick, we might as well go all the way.  :)  There's no "print fizz; print buzz" as your comment claims.  (If there were, that may be justifiably a violation).  The string being output is exactly the single string specified; it's just dynamically generated.  And if the output changes, you no longer have FizzBuzz.

Comment: @cHao okay now the nitpicker gets nitpicked upon. Still the problem stays the same, as the string is a dynamic concatenation of Fizz and Buzz and not FizzBuzz. The fact that the print-statement prints it after it got assembled doesn't change the underlying problem. See provided link to ChrisWue's answer.

Comment: @Vogel612: I've seen it.  And i feel it's paranoid to assume that a well-known problem is suddenly going to rather radically change its specification.  Whatever happened to YAGNI?

Comment: @cHao I am just gonna refer you to my previous comment: "[...] nitpicking in the context of a FizzBuzz itself, but all else equal it's a violation of the acceptance criteria IMO" and Acceptance Critera beats YAGNI....

Comment: @Vogel612: Except that the acceptance criteria are met.  `fizz = 'Fizz'; buzz = 'Buzz'; puts ("#{fizz}#{buzz}" == "FizzBuzz")` outputs "true".

Comment: @cHao that's why IMO! The acceptance criteria is: 3 puts $s1, 5 puts $2, 15 puts $s3, (luckily $s1+$s2 = $s3). Well either way this is getting long, and it doesn't look like we are getting to a close. If you want to discuss this further I suggest you open up a chatroom. Not gonna keep the discussion here ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15723/discussion-between-chao-and-vogel612).

Answer (score 4):

I cannot add anything new to the comments of other users regarding your code. But striving for the most declarative code I can think of, I'd write:

```
class Integer
  def divisible_by?(n)
    (self % n).zero?
  end
end

1.upto(100) do |n| 
  string = case
    when n.divisible_by?(3) && n.divisible_by?(5) then 'fizzbuzz'
    when n.divisible_by?(3) then 'fizz'
    when n.divisible_by?(5) then 'buzz'
    else n.to_s
  end

  puts(string)
end
```

(Well, actually I think `strings = 1.upto(100).lazy.map { ... }` + `print_lines(strings)` would be still more declarative, but this style is not -yet- idiomatic in Ruby).

Comment: +1 for the `divisible_by?` method from me too. Was considering the same thing (actually, I went looking for such a method in a while back, figuring it might already be built in, but nope). Don't know if I'd find the `.lazy.map` construction more declarative, compared to a simple `each`, though

Comment: @Flambino. Yes, it's not clear it would be better. But I think it would be more modular, at least (and more functional). First, you get the result (`lines`). Now what do you want? printing them? ok, then `print_lines(lines)` or whatever.

Comment: `self` is required in the definition of `divisible_by`. An even simpler example is `class Integer; def mod(n); % n; end; end`. `4.mod(3) => "n\n"`. Do you know the rule that requires `self` to be explicit here? (Other rules, for example, are that write accessors must include `self.` and `self.class` is required to obtain `self`'s class.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would implement this in ruby, not as a golfing or obscure route, but rather making use of a lot of best practice ruby idioms:

```
class FizzBuzz
  def initialize(start = 1, last = 100)
    @start = start
    @last = last
  end

  def each
    range.each do |n|
      yield fizzbuzz(n)
    end
  end

  private
  attr_reader :start, :last

  def range
    start..last
  end

  def divisible_by_3(n)
    n % 3 == 0
  end

  def divisible_by_5(n)
    n % 5 == 0
  end

  def divisible_by_15(n)
    n % 15 == 0
  end

  def fizzbuzz(n)
    case
      when divisible_by_15(n)
        'fizzbuzz'
      when divisible_by_3(n)
        'fizz'
      when divisible_by_5(n)
        'buzz'
      else
        n
    end    
  end
end

FizzBuzz.new(1,50).each {|f|  puts f}
```

What's idiomatic here?

- Start with a class.  Default values in initializer yields the most basic example.
- Small public API.  The rest of the methods are private, to indicate they aren't expected to be used directly.
- private attr_reader reads better than using instance variables directly
- separating the responsibility of output vs the generation of the data.  The FizzBuzz class simply iterate over the range and returns the results.  The user of the class is responsible for output, hence the each block at the bottom.
- small methods.   Each method does one thing, and is named in such a way that you can easily tell what it does. reading the short method is easy to confirm what the method does.
- note that divisible by 3 and divisible by 5 implies divisible by 15.  One could make an argument for making that method just use the previous methods: `divisible_by_3 && divisible_by_5` but I think think dividing by 15 is better.

Yes, this is significantly longer than your example... But on larger projects with more complicated logic, following these idioms will greatly enhance the readability and thus, maintenance, of your code base.

Another version of the fizzbuzz method could be:

```
  def fizzbuzz(n)
    divisible_by_15(n) and return 'fizzbuzz'
    divisible_by_3(n)  and return 'fizz'
    divisible_by_5(n)  and return 'buzz'
    n
  end
```

This eliminates a supposed code smell of the case statement, but it's debatable whether it's better or not.   Some people object to more than one return statement; others object to case statements...  I could go either way.

Comment: I like your use of a class, but I could say a thing or two about using `15` the way you have. Might want to put this up for review yourself. =;)-

Comment: I noted that in a bullet point - and in this simple example it's easy to say that something divisible by both 3 and 5 is also divisible by 15.   If these strategies did something more complex, though, would require reusing the existing 3 and 5 methods.   It's just a matter of whether your problem domain allows for that semantic optimization.